# Changing block comment styles in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, comments

I want to have comments work in the traditional way they do In C in Apple's Xcode. I have installed [VVDocumentor](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) and I really like how the default way it comments is, i.e.:

`/*
  * Comments go here
  */`

`/* 
  * multiple
  * lined
  * comment
  */`

I hoped to be able to use [CComment](https://github.com/flexih/Xcode-CComment), to help me do that, but what it does is just

`/* comments go here */`

`/* multiple
lined
comment*/`

Which is ugly. VVDocumentor doesn't help either because if one hits enter the result is

`/*
  * multiple
  * lined
  * comment
new comment here
  */`

Which is unhelpful.

I'd like to modify Xcode such that the behavior of hitting enter takes this.

`/*
 * multiple
 * lined
 * comment
 */`

to this

`/*
 * multiple
 * line
 * comment
 * new comment line here
 */`

I'm aware that you can simply block comment, by selecting text and pressing ⌘ + /, but that doesn't achieve what I'm looking for, and more importantly when I'm commenting I must press it again every time I press enter.

I'm sure someone else is looking for this since it's a pretty common style however my google-fu has failed thus far.